# Как автоматически создать переменную?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook, javascript-events

У меня есть функция, которая перебирает массив и создает кнопки. Скажите, как я могу создать автоматически для каждой кнопки новую переменную вида
`const [test] = useSound(SoundImport.test);`

```
function createNewButton() {
    return props.newResult.map(() => (
      <button className={styles.buttonPlay} id='button3'>
        {props.newResult}
      </button>
    ));
  }
```

Проект на реакте. Не знаю в чистом js это делается или есть методы на реакте

Comment: Никак, только можете записать в массив какой-то. Ну или создать объект, который может принимать строку как ключ для создания, и записывать туда свои данные

Comment: а как мне потом эти данные вывести как переменные, чтобы работать с ними как с переменными?

Comment: Ну если массив то пробежать по массиву циклом `for of` например, если объект, то циклом `for in` к примеру

Answer (score 0):

Было бы лучше уточнить для чего тебе это нужно, чтобы предложить правильный варинт. Пока есть только 2 идеи реализации того, что тебе нужно. (если я правильно тебя понял)

```js
function createNewButton() {
    const buttonCallback = useCallback((item) => {
      // делаешь то, что надо
    }, [])

    return props.newResult.map((item) => (
      <button className={styles.buttonPlay} onClick={buttonCallback } id='button3'>
        {props.newResult}
      </button>
    ));
}
```

ЛИБО

```js
const callbacks = {}

function createNewButton() {
   
    return props.newResult.map((it, i) => {
      const func = () => { ///.... }
      callbacks[i] = func;
      return <button className={styles.buttonPlay} onClick={func} id='button3'>
        {props.newResult}
      </button>
    });
}
```