# Как автоматически создать переменную в js?

Tags: javascript

У меня с сервера приходит ответ в виде массива [1,2,3]. Подскажите, как мне проверить массив и для каждого элемента создать константу формата const [letter] = useSound("1.mp4"); и вставить ее в код страницы т.е. чтобы данная переменная создавалась не руками, а автоматически. Слышал, что можно сделать через объект, но не понятно как потом обратиться к переменной формата, который я указал

Comment: ничего не ясно, в какой код страницы вставлять? причём тут константы? нужно больше инфы, что и куда планируется вставлять

Comment: Какую глобальную задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1407229/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b8

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1407154/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e#comment2501623_1407154